# How to access Tex interface on mac

Tags: installing

I downloaded the smaller Tex version (because I don't have a lot of space on my computer) from http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html onto my mac. However, once everything is installed, I can't find any Tex application on my computer. Could someone please explain what I should do ?
PS When I ran `tex --version` on my terminal, it said that it is TeX 3.14159265 and when I ran `which tex` it said `/Library/TeX/texbin/tex`.

Comment: Did you try to run `tex --version` on the console?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) there is no tex application. You'll have to use the terminal or what ever editor you use. Why did you install the smaller version? This is only for users who really know what they are doing.

Comment: In general the basic TeX binaries are all command line interfaces. So you need to use your terminal to utilize them. However there are several TeX specific editors around which happen to also include a button or two to run TeX related binaries on the current file via a graphical user interface. So please run `tex --version` in your terminal to ensure that TeX is installed and in your path.

Comment: Are you talking about the tex live utility app?

Comment: But did `tex --version` return anything useful (so nothing like `command not found`, but more like `TeX 3.14159265` and some more lines)? It should not give you any path (that would have been `whereis tex` if `whereis` is available on a Mac). At this stage we don't need the path to the executable, we just need to make sure it is correctly installed.

Comment: @Skillmon it is `which tex`

Comment: Good so TeX is correctly installed. Just for fun save the following as a file `example.tex`: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{duckuments}\begin{document}\blindduck\end{document}`. Then run `pdflatex example.tex`.

Comment: The general workflow would be the following from now on: You write a file containing your document and save it as `<file-name>.tex`. You can use which ever editor you like for that. Note however that there are specialized IDEs for TeX around which might ease the process. Then you run the appropriate TeX binary on that file in your console: `pdflatex <file-name>.tex` would be an example. Of course if you want to use XeLaTeX that would be `xelatex <file-name>.tex`. Most TeX IDEs however provide means to run TeX on the current file without using the console (and previewing it).

Comment: Examples of IDEs would be TeXstudio, Texmaker, TeXworks, ... There are plenty. There is a question on this site about the different editors.

Comment: Here is a list of available editors: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: Since you're on a Mac, I would recommend using [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop), which is a good well maintained editor native to the Mac. To add more packages if needed you can use [TeX Live Utility](https://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/).